# CSS link behavior override/inheritance: FF/Chrome give random results with Wordpress customization

Tags: css, wordpress, inheritance, hyperlink

I've added some custom CSS code to a Wordpress.com theme to alter link formatting. (I'm a beginner, but I attempted to research this and found some code that looked reasonable.)

Chrome is getting it about 90% right and FF about 10% right. Is this inevitable and I should revert to theme defaults, or is there something I can do differently to make this change work in common browsers?

To be more specific, "border: none" is working in both browsers, but the custom color for the link is usually missing in FF--which means no one but me can tell it's a link. Even in Chrome it's only usually the right color. And, the color I set for "active" isn't displaying at all. Meanwhile, the block quote change is rendering in both browsers.

All I added was this CSS (added in the edit window they provide which by definition means it's at the end of the total CSS for the page, so that should make it override or inherit, I thought).

```
div.entry-content a:link {
    color: #2C60BA;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

div.entry-content a:active {
    color: #3A93BC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

blockquote {
    float: none;
    width: 24em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove the :link, and just have:

```
div.entry-content a {
    color: #2C60BA;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Also, just in case your theme has overrides for visited links, you might also want to include a rule for visited as well to be sure:

```
div.entry-content a, div.entry-content a:visited{
color: #2C60BA;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: Bryant, thank you. I made the first change you suggested, removing ":link" and it solved the display problem perfectly in both browsers. Genius! But, the links are still not displaying the intended color when active. Any more thoughts? Finally, my theme doesn't appear to have a "visited" setting so I think I can get away with not overriding it. Thanks.

Comment: Bryant, a p.s. and another thank you. An experiment I ran using your "visited" code but changing "visited" to "active" clued me in--I had misunderstood "active." For what I wanted when I stated "active" I actually needed "hover." So I replaced "active" with "hover" in the next block of code and now all is well. Thank you so much. I'm sure I'll be back! (Just for edification, why does it work, in the first block of code, to remove ":link"? Was I making a basic syntax error or is something to do with the inheritance situation or . . . ??)

Comment: No problem, and just be aware that if your theme/plugins have a selectors that are 'more specific', those could override yours, so make those selectors as specific as possible.  If needed, you can also add in an !important tag to ensure your code gets precedence... i.e (color: #fff !important; )  The :link isn't really a proper selector, if you just want to target the link, all you need is the a.  I mentioned the :visited option as well, because if that were defined in your CSS, all the pages that you've visited already would appear with the old CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Bryant provided the key insight in his first answer and my problem, after further experimenting, is now fully solved (see commments). I'm new here and not sure how to mark this resolved, but am guessing this is how to do it. Thanks again.